# Why is the head getting changed when changing a different node in a linked list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, reference

How is the head getting changed when `cur` is changed after we replace `cur` with `cur.next` (`else` statement)?

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        cur=head
        while cur.val and cur.next:
            if cur.val==cur.next.val:
                cur.next=cur.next.next
            else:            
                cur=cur.next
            print(cur)  
        return head
```

I know that when we did `cur=head` we are creating a reference so any change made on the head will be updated (because `cur` and `head` have the same id) but when entering in the `else` the `cur` is changed and `cur` and `head` don't have the same id anymore (inside the `else` only the `cur` is changed) but when we get back to the `if` clause, any modification on the `cur` is affecting the head, too. How can this happen they don't even have the same id?

Comment: Did you check if they in fact don't have the same id? `print(id(cur), id(head))`

Comment: Yes I did before entering the else they have the same id but once it gets into the else the id of the cur is changed (but still when they get to the if any modification on the cur effect the head)

Comment: Pretty sure the ids are different for cur and head once you run this, if not then it is not a code problem it is something else.
if you are referring to the leetcode problem then this would fail because leetCode wants you to drop the two(or more) duplicates, not keep one of them, but that might be something else.

Comment: Not your question, but the `while` condition should not have `curr.val`. That makes no sense. It is distracting to see a question about how code works, when that code doesn't do it right.

Comment: How did you build the list in the first place? Sounds like your list consists of a bunch of references to a *single* instance of `ListNode`, rather than references to *distinct* instances of `LIstNode`.

Comment: `deleteDuplicates` should probably not care about the value of any particular node when deciding when to stop. `cur.next is None` is sufficient to detect the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code should not have `cur.val` in the `while` condition. It makes no sense to make an exception for when `cur.val` is 0.

Now to the question: `head` does not necessarily change: only when it has a duplicate value it will mutate. Whether or not it has a duplicate itself, if there are duplicates further in the list, the **chain** that `head` references does change. So you could interpret that as `head` being changed, but then that is only "remotely".

It may help to visualise it. Let's say we have a linked list with 4 nodes, and they have values 1, 2, 2, and 3. There is a duplicate, so the resulting list should have one node omitted from it.

Here is how the state looks when `cur=head` is executed, just before the loop starts:

```
head  cur
  │    │
┌─┴────┴────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ val:   1  │    │ val: 2    │    │ val: 2    │    │ val: 3    │
│ next: ─────────┤ next: ─────────┤ next: ─────────┤ next: None│ 
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Then in the loop, 1 is compared with 2, so we get into the `else` block, and `cur` is assigned another reference, ... the one that is at `cur.next` (which happens to be also `head.next`). So after that assignment, `cur` will reference the same as `head.next`:

```
head                cur
  │                  │
┌─┴─────────┐    ┌───┴───────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ val:   1  │    │ val: 2    │    │ val: 2    │    │ val: 3    │
│ next: ─────────┤ next: ─────────┤ next: ─────────┤ next: None│ 
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

In the second iteration, the `if` condition is true, and so a *mutation* happens (i.e. an **attribute** is assigned to): `cur.next = cur.next.next`. The right hand expression is a reference to the last node in our list, and the `cur` node is mutated to reference it with its `next` attribute:

```
head                cur
  │                  │          ┌───────────────┐
┌─┴─────────┐    ┌───┴───────┐  │ ┌───────────┐ │  ┌───────────┐
│ val:   1  │    │ val: 2    │  │ │ val: 2    │ └──┤ val: 3    │
│ next: ─────────┤ next: ───────┘ │ next: ─────────┤ next: None│ 
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

At this point, the second node with value 2 is detached -- there are no more references to it, so it can be garbage collected. As we cannot reach it anymore, there is no difference in picturing this state without it:

```
head                cur
  │                  │          
┌─┴─────────┐    ┌───┴───────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ val:   1  │    │ val: 2    │    │ val: 3    │
│ next: ─────────┤ next: ─────────┤ next: None│ 
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

This mutation was done to the node that `cur` references, but because also `head.next` references that node, this mutation can be "seen" via `head` (by following the `next` chain). It is not a direct mutation of `head`'s attributes, but further down the line there a change can be seen.

In the next iteration, the value at `cur` is compared with 3, which means we get into the `if` block, and `cur = cur.next` makes `cur` reference the last node. Note that this statement is an assignment to a *name* -- it does not mutate any object. To mutate an object, one has to assign to an *attribute*.

Anyway, we get in this state:

```
head                                 cur
  │                                   │
┌─┴─────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───┴───────┐
│ val:   1  │    │ val: 2    │    │ val: 3    │
│ next: ─────────┤ next: ─────────┤ next: None│ 
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Now the `while` condition is false, and `head` is returned to the caller, while the name `cur` is now discarded. So the caller sees this:

```
(returned)
  │
┌─┴─────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ val:   1  │    │ val: 2    │    │ val: 3    │
│ next: ─────────┤ next: ─────────┤ next: None│ 
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

I hope this clarifies it.